Hiding the global javascript context with my own
I'm reading the MDN web docs on globalThis.
It says:

Note: The globalThis property is configurable and writable so that
code authors can hide it when executing untrusted code and prevent
exposing the global object.

I want to do exactly this, creating a sandbox of sorts so that a function can be written which accesses variables in the sandbox without needing to prefix it with anything and also preventing any variables not in the sandbox object from being accessible - like an improved alternative to the deprecated "with" construct which will fail to find anything not in the global context I define.
I wrote a proof of concept running in an ES6 module:
let myContext = { a:1, b:2 }
let f = ()=> {
    let savedGlobal = globalThis
    globalThis = myContext
    let ret = a+b
    savedGlobal.globalThis = savedGlobal
    return ret
}
f()

As an explanation, I am first saving the current value of globalThis to a local variable, as I expect that otherwise the original value won't be accessible from my new global context.  Then I hide the existing global context by overwriting it with my own, which the documentation seems to suggest is possible.  Then I try to assign a local variable to the result of a+b which should be 1+2 = 3, then I restore the global context from the local saved value and return the value I calculated.
If I log the variables, I see that globalThis is the Window object before I assign to it, and it's myContext after, but I still get a reference error "a is not defined" despite the fact that I would expect that it would find it in the now global context "myContext".  It also successfully ran the console.log despite the fact that I would expect it to no longer be visible after reassigning globalThis.

What about using globalThis.a not a?

Reassigning globalThis doesn't change the top-level global binding object that JS uses to perform identifier resolution, so changing globalThis to try and augment your scope chain won't work.

@evolutionxbox that would work, but would make a lot of extra work (the sandbox is intended to allow code to be safely written manually before a transpiler is implemented, so that code needs to have this extra "annotation" on every variable created, reducing readability and increasing the chance for errors)

@NickParsons I suppose there's no way to change that binding then?

@Michael It's determined by the host environment so not normally (unless the host provides a way (eg), but in browsers, you can't). I'm not too sure what your exact goal is and how you'd execute the let ret = a + b; line (as I imagine it's user-supplied), but perhaps take a look at similar questions like this.

There's also a proposal for ShadowRealms which could help with stuff like this down the line.

As commented in your question, you will not be able to customize the javascript identifier resolution process...
You can make your own workaround like this:


function F ()
{
  return this.a + this.b;
}

var a = 5;
var b = 6;

// Unbound
console.log(F());
// Outputs 11, because this is globalThis in browsers (undefined in Node).

// Bound to context A
console.log(F.apply({a: 1, b: 2}));
// Outputs 3, because the this inside the function is replaced with the object above.

// ...
// Bound to context N
console.log(F.apply({a: 3, b: 4}));
// Outputs 7, because the this inside the function is replaced with the object above.



I hope this helps solving your problem.
